# Is it ok to cast a NSdictionary object to NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it ok to cast a NSdictionary object to NSMutableDictionary?

```
NSDictionary *dict;
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)dict;
```

Tried this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not. If you want a mutable dictionary, make one:

```
NSMutableDictionary* mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
```

Do not forget in accordance with [the rules](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) you own `mutableDict` and must release it when you are done with it.

Comment: You can also easily use [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:myOriginalDictionary]; which will return an autoreleased object.

Comment: It's wrong to assume it's a mutable dictionary... If it isn't, then you could potentially send the object methods that the class does not respond to, which will crash your program. It's better to be safe.